# How to delete n characters from string with regex

Tags: regex

I try to use regex to delete the last n characters from a string.
For example:

My input: `azerty`
My expected Output: `azer`

I want to have a regular expression that does this.

Comment: [`.{2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/oQ3yT1/1), depending on your regex engine.

Comment: Does your language not have a substring function...? Regex seems like overkill for something this simple.

Comment: No. that's why I use regex

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this regular expression ([try and view an explanation it online](https://regex101.com/r/oQ3yT1/1)):

```
.{2}$
```